# How to catch an Exception throw by Azure Table in an async Azure Function HTTP Triggered function

Tags: c#, .net-core, azure-functions, azure-table-storage, azure-function-async

I have an Azure Function HTTP triggered function which writes to Azure Table that may end in duplicated entries. I noticed that even if I try/catch'd the whole function, there will still be an Exception "leaked" to the function runner thus returning HTTP 500. Is there any way to catch this kind of exception?

Here's a minified version of the code:

```
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage;

namespace FunctionTest
{
    public class Entry
    {
        public string PartitionKey { get; set; }
        public string RowKey { get; set; }
    }
    public static class Debug
    {
        [FunctionName("Debug")]
        public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", "post", Route = null)]
            HttpRequest req,
            [Table("Debug")]
            IAsyncCollector<Entry> tableBinding,
            ILogger log)
        {
            try
            {
                await tableBinding.AddAsync(new Entry()
                {
                    PartitionKey = "1111",
                    RowKey = "1111",
                });
                await tableBinding.FlushAsync();
            }
            catch (StorageException)
            {
                // we expect an Exception "The specified entity already exists"
                return new OkObjectResult("This passes test");
            }

            return new OkObjectResult("This passes test too");
        }
    }
}
```

The code is written under Azure Function runtime 2.0 (the .NET Core one).

Trigger `/api/debug` twice or more and you will see:

- HTTP 500
- The `catch{}` code is entered, and still returns an HTTP 500(!)
- In Application Insights, two table dependency call per request (shouldn't happen, the documentation says table do not have auto retry)

Comment: You aren't catching all the exception types so of course an exception can leak. Are you 100% sure that you aren't missing an exception by not having a generic `system.exception` catch block?

Comment: It is also possible, but he said, that the flow enters the `catch` block and still reports 500.

Comment: @Charleh I've already done experiments before I came here to ask, and catching Exception simply doesn't work. The code provided is a minimal version to reproduce the problem, it's not what I wrote in the actual project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess, that using `IAsyncCollector<>` breaks things here. If you want to avoid such problems, try to exchange the following binding:

```
[Table("Debug")] IAsyncCollector<Entry> tableBinding
```

to:

```
[Table("Debug")] CloudTable tableBinding
```

Then, instead of using `tableBinding.AddAsync()` use the following snippet:

```
var op = TableOperation.Insert(new Entry());
await tableBinding.ExecuteAsync(op);
```

With that approach, you should be able to catch the exception, without leaking it to the Functions runtime.

Comment: This works for me. Note: class Entry needs to implement TableEntity.

Answer (score -1):

Your try/catch block should look like following to catch all errors

```
try
{

}
catch (StorageException)
{
    return new OkObjectResult("This passes test");
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    // return different error code
}
```

Comment: The code provided is only a minimal version to reproduce the problem. In my own code I've tried multiple ways including catching the generic Exception, and I have extensive logging so I'm pretty sure StorageException is the only exception type.